# How do I reduce execution time of this code

Tags: android, android-canvas, execution-time

I'm trying to create and share an image of 1920x1920 wherein the first half screenshot of the app and a simple shadow of the image is printed. In the second half, the app icon and some multi-line text are printed. Here's a shared image from the app.
[image]

I already reduced the image quality while compression, but it still takes a lot of time(around 1 second) when this code runs for the first time. Any kind of help would be appreciated and also suggest some better way of doing it.

```
private void shareScreenShot() {
        String text="Download Sarkari Bank App from play store";
        String link="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sarkaribank";
        View rootView = findViewById(R.id.layoutView).getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap ss = rootView.getDrawingCache();
        int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();

        //adding ss and shadow
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ss, 0, statusBarHeight, ss.getWidth(), ss.getHeight()-statusBarHeight-getNavBarHeight(this) );

        final int canvasWidth = 1920;
        final int canvasHeight = 1920;
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint shadowPaint = new Paint();
        shadowPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00cbff"));

        Paint border = new Paint();
        border.setColor(Color.parseColor("#095baf"));
        border.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        border.setStrokeWidth(10);

        canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight), border);

        border.setStrokeWidth(5);

        int nh = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * (768.0 / bitmap.getWidth()));
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 768, nh, true);

        Rect shadow = new Rect(0, 0, scaled.getWidth(), scaled.getHeight());

        //small distance between shadow and SS
        float sd = 96 * scaled.getWidth() / scaled.getHeight();

        float translateX = (canvasWidth / 2 - scaled.getWidth()) / 2;
        float translateY = (canvasHeight - scaled.getHeight()) / 2;
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(translateX + sd, translateY + sd);
        canvas.drawRect(shadow, shadowPaint);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(translateX, translateY);
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawRect(shadow, border);
        canvas.restore();

        //add icon
        int left = canvasWidth / 2;
        int right = canvasWidth;
        int blockHeight = canvasHeight / 12;

        Rect iconRect = new Rect(left, 3 * blockHeight, right, 5 * blockHeight);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logo);

        int iconX = (iconRect.left + (iconRect.width() / 2)) - blockHeight;
        int iconY = (iconRect.top + (iconRect.height() / 2)) - blockHeight;
        iconRect.left = iconX;
        iconRect.top = iconY;
        iconRect.right = iconX + 2 * blockHeight;
        iconRect.bottom = iconY + 2 * blockHeight;
        canvas.drawBitmap(icon, null, iconRect, null);

        //add text
        String t1 = "SarkariBank.com",
                t2 = "These details are shared by sarkaribank mobile app. You can download it from playstore.",
                t3 = "Go on playstore and search sarkaribank then install it.",
                t4 = "Thanks for sharing!";

        TextPaint headingPaint = new TextPaint();
        headingPaint.setTextSize(blockHeight / 2);
        TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(blockHeight / 4);
        headingPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#095baf"));

        Rect t1Rect = new Rect(left, 5 * blockHeight, right, 6 * blockHeight);
        Rect t2Rect = new Rect(left + (int) translateX, 6 * blockHeight, right - (int) translateX, 7 * blockHeight);
        Rect t3Rect = new Rect(left + (int) translateX, 7 * blockHeight, right - (int) translateX, 8 * blockHeight);
        Rect t4Rect = new Rect(left, 8 * blockHeight, right, 9 * blockHeight);

        drawText(canvas, t1Rect, t1, headingPaint);
        drawText(canvas, t2Rect, t2, textPaint);
        drawText(canvas, t3Rect, t3, textPaint);
        drawText(canvas, t4Rect, t4, headingPaint);

        Uri uri = saveBitmap(result);
        Log.i("start time",stopwatch.toString());
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        String shareBody = text + "\n" + link;
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }

    private int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void drawText(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, String textOnCanvas, TextPaint textPaint){
        StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(textOnCanvas, textPaint, rect.width(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, 1, true);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(rect.left, rect.top);
        sl.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    public int getNavBarHeight(Context c) {
        int result = 0;
        boolean navBarExists = getResources().getBoolean(getResources().getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android"));

        if(navBarExists) {
            //The device has a navigation bar
            Resources resources = c.getResources();

            int orientation = resources.getConfiguration().orientation;
            int resourceId;
            if (isTablet(c)){
                resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? "navigation_bar_height" : "navigation_bar_height_landscape", "dimen", "android");
            }  else {
                resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? "navigation_bar_height" : "navigation_bar_width", "dimen", "android");
            }

            if (resourceId > 0) {
                return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean isTablet(Context c) {
        return (c.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
    }

    public Uri saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File imagesFolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
        Uri uri = null;
        try {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(imagesFolder, "shared_image.jpeg");

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();

            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.sarkaribank.fileprovider", file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("oops", "IOException while trying to write file for sharing: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return uri;
    }
```

Comment: use profiler to determine which methods take most time, and then looks for optimisations for them, or alternatives

Comment: I tried but app gets stopped with SIGABRT error whenever I attach profiler

Comment: I don't think "a second" is a lot of time for executing those io blocks. You can simply show a preloader/spinner while the process executes so it won't look obvious.